# Why does aggregating paginated query takes less time than fetching the entire table

Tags: pagination, azure-sql-database

I have a table in my database and I have it indexed over three columns: `PropertyId`, `ConceptId` and `Sequence`. This particular table has about 90,000 rows in it and it is indexed over these three properties.

Now, when I run this query, the total time required is greater than 2 minutes:

```
SELECT *
FROM MSC_NPV
ORDER BY PropertyId, ConceptId, Sequence
```

However, if I paginate the query like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM MSC_NPV
ORDER BY PropertyId, ConceptId, Sequence
OFFSET x * 10000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

the aggregate time (x goes from 0 to 8) required is only around 20 seconds.

This seems counterintuitive to me because the pagination requires additional operations over and beyond simpler queries and we're adding on the additional latency required for sequential network calls because I haven't parallelized this query at all. And, I know it's not a caching issue because running these queries one after the other does not affect the latencies very much.

So, my question is this: why is one so much faster than the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a prolonged search into what's going on here, I discovered that the reason behind this difference in performance (> 2 minutes) was due to hosting the database on Azure. Since Azure partitions any tables you host on it across multiple partitions (i.e. multiple machines), running a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM MSC_NPV
ORDER BY PropertyId, ConceptId, Sequence
```

would run more slowly because the query pulls data from all the partitions in before ordering them, which could result in multiple queries across multiple partitions on the same table. By paginating the query over indexed properties I was looking at a particular partition and querying over the table stored there, which is why it performed significantly better than the un-paginated query.

To prove this, I ran another query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MSC_NPV
ORDER BY Narrative
OFFSET x * 10000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

This query ran anemically when compared to the first paginated query because `Narrative` is not a primary key and therefore is not used by Azure to build a partition key. So, ordering on `Narrative` required the same operation as the first query and additional operations on top of that because the entire table had to be gotten beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

> This seems counterintuitive to me because the pagination requires additional operations over and beyond simpler queries

Pagination queries some times works very fast,if you have the right index...

For example,with below query

```
OFFSET x * 10000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10000 ROWS ONLY
```

the maximum rows you might read is 20000 only..below is an example which proves the same

[image]

> RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="60" ActualRowsRead="60"

but with `select *` query.. you are reading all the rows

Comment: Your haven't answered my question at all. According to what you have provided, the wait times should steadily increase as I aggregated over x (i.e. `x = 1` costs less time than `x = 2` and so on) but that isn't happening. I'm getting a constant latency for each query and the total time to run all the queries (20 seconds) is still much less than the time required to fetch the same data in one query (> 2 minutes) and you haven't addressed that point at all.

Comment: Is this not your question `This seems counterintuitive to me because the pagination requires additional operations over and beyond simpler queries`

Comment: No, that was an observation that the time required to get all pages in a database was much less than the time to get the entire database seemed strange.